# How to enable/ disable react form based on condition

Tags: reactjs

I have an react js form.I would like to know how to enable/disable all form input control based on condition.please check my below code and advise how to do this...

```
return (
      <form id ="frm" onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>

      <div className="animated fadeIn">
                <div className="form-group row">
<Button type="button"   text="Back" size="sm" onClick={this.onBackButtonClick} color="danger" className="pull-right  ml-1 "><i className="fa fa-ban"></i> Back</Button>
                       <Button type="submit" size="sm" color="success"  className="pull-right  ml-1 "><i className="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Save</Button>

                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">First Name</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" name="FirstName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.FirstName} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>

                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Last Name</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" name="LastName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtLastName" placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.LastName} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>

                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email Id</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="email" name ="EmailId" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtEmailId" placeholder="EmailId" value={this.state.EmailId} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Mobile No</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" name ="MobileNo" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtMobileNo" placeholder="Mobile No" value={this.state.MobileNo} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
                  </div>

                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Division</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                     <select name ="DivisionId" className="form-control" required value={this.state.DivisionId} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
                        {DivisionList}
                      </select>   
                  </div>


           /div>
          </form>
    );
```

***ComponentDidMount Event to check condition :-***

```
componentDidMount() {
if (this.props.match.params.mode=="Edit"){
// enable form control
}
else
{
// disable form control
}
```

Comment: There is no basic information..  What is the condition for check?? What is ```this.onChangeHandler``` function doing?? No detail available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a state `isFormDisabled` for ex.
- use html `fieldset` inside the form and use `disabled` property and provide the value of `isFormDisabled`
- use your logic to enable/disable based on your needs

**Code Sample**

```js
    ...
    state = {
        isFormDisabled: false
    }


    componentDidMount(){
      if (this.props.match.params.mode == "Edit") {
          this.setState({isFormDisabled: false})
      }
      else {
          this.setState({isFormDisabled: true})
      }
    }

    ...
    //inside render fun...
    return (
        <form id ="frm" onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
            <fieldset disabled={isFormDisabled}>
            <div className="animated fadeIn">
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">First Name</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" name="FirstName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.FirstName} required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                    </div>
              ...
           </fieldset>
              ...
```

Comment: thanks for reply,this works fine but i have forgot to mention button inside the form.I need to enable button only and all other input field should be disable.please help me...

Comment: you can wrap the button with `legend` to make a button enabled inside a fieldset... see https://codesandbox.io/s/fieldset-button-enable-gjqrx  for a sample ... use that and do your logic accordingly .. if you need more, update your question with exactly what you want and provide your existing code

Comment: You can use the "isFormDisabled" on button directly using the disabled attribute.
Something like this, <button disabled={this.state.isFormDisabled} />